# how do you prove ¬E ∧ A, A → (B ∧ C), B → D∴ C ∧ (D ∧ ¬E)

Tags: logic

I have to give a formal proof of this argument.
I put my premises, and got to here:
~E /\ A :PR
A->(B/\C) :PR
B->D :PR
And we want the conclusion to be C/(D/~E)
~E :/\E1
A :/\E1
But stumped on how to use the conditional rule afterwards. I know that I need a subproof to answer the question, but I don't know how to construct it, and to get to the answer.

Comment: What rules do you know ? The 1st premise needs Conjunction elimination and then the 2nd premise uses Conditional elimination. And so on.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand different subjects teach so called "Logic" differently. With that said there are many methods of rules. Which set of rules are you required to use for your class? There is no one for all logic. These days this what you provide is Mathematical logic. There are others. Usually proof questions frequently use some sort of natural deduction rules while other use a set of rules deemed Copi rules after a famous  philosophy book on logic. Introduction rules and elimination rules frequently mean math natural deduction rules. You must make assumptions to do this proof.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to assume the conclusion false and then deduce that there is a contradiction. This can prove the conclusion true.

¬E ∧ A    (1)

A → (B ∧ C)    (2)

B → D    (3)

∴ C ∧ (D ∧ ¬E)    (4)

assume: ¬(C ∧ (D ∧ ¬E))    (5)

∴ ¬C    (6) (From 5)

∴ ¬(D ∧ ¬E)    (7) (From 5)

**∴ ¬D    (8) (From 7)**

∴ E    (9) (From 7)

∴ A    (10) (From 1)

∴ (B ∧ C)    (11) (From 2)

∴ B    (12) (From 11)

**∴ D    (13) (From 3; Contradicts with 8)**

∴ C ∧ (D ∧ ¬E)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof. If I was doing this by hand I would have probably regrouped the steps a bit, done lines 8 and 10 earlier, but that is purely cosmetic.

Edit: The instructor/grader may want a separate step for adding the parenthesis around D ^ ~E.

[image]